# Re-install R / Rstudio and migrating library

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to move as many files as possible to be on my D: drive instead of my C: drive, and if possible trying to include RStudio in this, and I'm wondering how much of this is feasible and how painlessly. This includes: version of R, base folder for R, Rstudio, and packages.

Now, since OneDrive was annoying me, I have these packages installed in a custom folder I made (and overwritten the relevant part in Rprofiles, following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@ValidScience/how-to-fix-rstudios-package-installation-on-windows-10-c1e602bf3a1f) and all seems functional for the past few months), so I was hoping that I would be able to uninstall R and Rstudio, reinstall everything in a custom folder in D:, and easily migrate packages.

I'm not too worried about the R and Rstudio but feel a little lost about the most painless way to re-install the packages (which include some non-standard non-CRAN packages) - it seems that there are some answers to these already that suggest it is simple to migrate packages if installed in a custom folder, but they do not include re-installing R   or RStudio. Any advice on this would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing the exact same R version with the same configuration and everything, you could avoid reinstalling it if you just move the folder with installed libraries somewhere else and then create a `.Rprofile` file that would set `.libPaths` (not 100% sure what it's called) to the folder where your installed libraries are.

Comment: Ok, great, I don't need to tell Rstudio where R is installed at all?

Comment: If you also move the R installation itself (not just the libraries), then you'll also need to. That's done in the RStudio global settings.

Comment: Got it - really appreciate this!